# How can I implement A* so that it accounts for the size of the actor?

Tags: path-finding, collision-prediction

I'm trying to make a little A* implementation using polygon verticies as nodes instead of grids and I ran into the problem of figuring out what paths are wide enough to accommodate the actor moving through them.

Lets say the actor was 10x10 and the space between two verticies was only 5 units wide, the actor shouldn't be able to fit into that space but with the regular A* algorithm it would. How can I prevent this?

Comment: This pdf was linked in a previous question and purports to provide a solution to this and a few other A* limitations. https://harablog.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/beyondastar.pdf

Comment: Can you mark each *edge* with the maximum size of the actor, so that when A\* gets a list of edges/neighbors, you only tell A\* about the ones that are big enough for the actor?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't like the idea of altering A* for this and would instead create an abstract graph per actor size on which A* would run.

I would precalculate a waypoint network or coarse grid (see [The Mechanics of Influence Mapping: Representation, Algorithm & Parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20190717210940/http://aigamedev.com/open/tutorial/influence-map-mechanics/)) per actor size which only contains nodes, on which an actor could stand.

I would then use A* as usual on the waypoint network which suits the characters size.

This approach probably scales horribly with a very large number of different actor sizes. But if it's just a hand full, this should work fine.